# Importing from index files in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I cannot use index files for imports within my component library, but from the outside.
I'm using the following directory structure:

```
+ components
  | index.js
  + atoms
    | index.js
    + label
      | label.jsx
      | label.css
  + hoc
    | index.js
    + withFrame
      | withFrame.jsx
      | withFrame.css
  + clientSpecificStyle
    | index.js
    | clientLabel.jsx
```

The index files are just exporting a default import

```
// just one sample
export { default as Label } from './label/label;
```

What I want to do is being able to distinguish between typical (basic) styling of components and client specific styling.
My clientLabel is just a label surrounded with a frame:

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';

 // this doesn't work
 import Label from '../atoms/index';
 import withFrame from '../hoc/index';

 // this works
 import Label from '../atoms/label/label';
 import withFrame from '../hoc/withFrame/withFrame';

 @withFrame
 class ClientLabel extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <Label {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Label>
     );
   }
 }

 export default ClientLabel;
```

When used from the "outside" (i. e. a demo page located on same folder hierarchy as components) using imports from the component index file, it works as expected. But I cannot import the HoC and the Label from the index files within the ClientLabel (fails with component/function undefined). It works however, when using the HoC and Label component files directly for import. The topmost index file (for the whole library) looks like this

```
export * from './atoms/index;
export * from './clientSpecificStyle/index';
//...
```

As I expect this project to grow into many separate components, it'd be more convenient to use index files for all imports, hence allow me to reorganize code as I see fit and only changing one line of code in the corresponding index file.

Is it possible to get this to work?

---

My webpack (v. 3.6) config works - apart from this issue - as expected. Just for clarity, here's the dev-config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports =  {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.resolve('src', 'demo', 'demo.jsx')
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'react-hot-loader/webpack!babel-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
            'style-loader?sourceMap',
            'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve('src', 'demo', 'index.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: you do not need to add index. and also you changed the default to Label so the new import should be ```import { Label } from '../atoms'``` hope that makes sense

Comment: @ReiDien I can't believe I missed that... `import {Label} from '../atoms/(index)` did the trick... If you answer the question I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just for completeness: the correct way to import is

`import {Label} from '../atoms`

as I've done a named export.

All kudos go to @ReiDien